Can a subpanel ground originate from a separate circuit/conduit?
I have a 30amp pool subpanel wired with 10awg THHN through 3/4" schedule 40 PVC conduit. I'm considering installing a heat pump pool heater which will require a beefier subpanel.
Can I run 2x 4awg hot/hot and 1x 8awg neutral through the conduit and utilize a ground from a nearby junction box to serve as the subpanel ground? This is about 38% fill which would be a beast to pull particularly through old conduit, but seems like it would fit.
Most of the pool loads are 240v, so undersizing the neutral to the grounding conductor size seems appropriate based on calculated load. The only 120v load is the pool light and a receptacle for a powered pool vacuum. This would allow me to have an 80amp breaker to protect the sub panel.
Pool pump is ~10.1 amp 240v load, pool heater is 37amp 240v load. In the future I would like to add a second pump and possibly a second smaller heater so I'm trying to maximize available capacity.

@Jasen Sorry I should have been more specific - Schedule 40 PVC. Will edit.

Is it in the same building? Is the conduit accessible? EGC doesn't necessarily need to be inside the conduit.

Conduit goes from an interior junction box on one side of the house, down under the slab foundation, up to a junction box on an exterior wall on the opposite side of the house. There is a junction box for my HVAC compressor nearby which I would like to pigtail a ground to serve the subpanel ground bus.

Are the pool and compressor fed directly from the same upstream panel?  Is the compressor's ground wire back to the panel big enough for an 80A circuit?

@jay613 Both are fed from the same panel. Compressor ground is 8awg THHN, which should be sufficient for <=100 amp feed. From your questions can I infer running a ground separately is allowed provided it is sufficiently sized and originates from the same panel?

Doesn't have to be in the conduit so long as it's otherwise compliant.  Those two things were the most obvious gotchas.   Inspector might not like you doing this in a new subpanel installation.  The distance/routing/complexity will play into it.  Maybe establish a new junction box solely for ground to branch off to the new panel and compressor so an A/C tech cannot sever the new path.   Best talk to inspector first.

Ground needs to run with the conductors except in retrofit situations.  #8 copper bare ground.  Also note #6 is 65A, and you can squeeze 75A out of it if your conduit is 90C and you stop at an intermediate junction box to splice to #4 conductors for final connection to your 75C panels. A real PITA but can squeeze a few extra amps out of limited conduit space.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica That sounds like an answer, and also a somewhat uncommon use for the 90 degree column I have not seen before. Great idea!

You can't run ground separate from conductors except in a retrofit scenario when running with no ground was legal at the time the other wires were installed.
Downsizing the neutral is governed by NEC 220.61, and may be done based on the calculated load.
Now there's the 90 degree C cheat.  THHN and THWN-2 wire, by itself, is 90°C wire.  However, it is constrained by the thermal rating of enclosures it goes through and terminals it lands on. Consumer tier panels are generally 75°C rated, which is what lands us at 65A for 6 AWG.
If you exit a panel with 4 AWG wire, go to an intermediate junction box which is rated 90C and splice (using 90°C rated terminals) to 6 AWG wire.... and then do the same thing again at the other end... then the 6 AWG wire is entirely in a 90°C world and you're good to that amp rating (75 amps).
